# Faulting application w3wp.exe version 7.0 faulting module kernel32.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, crystal-reports-2008

I have an application (ASP.NET) which works fine on local debugging/IIS hosting. But as we deploy it to the server (Win 2008 R2), and click on one of the links(to generate a report), the reports gets generated but the whole application is down. On checking event viewer, we get the below error:

> Faulting application w3wp.exe, version 7.0.6002.18005, time stamp
> 0x49e03238, faulting module kernel32.dll, version 6.0.6002.19034, time
> stamp 0x52f30e80, exception code 0xe0434352, fault offset
> 0x000000000001674d, process id 0x1f088, application start time
> 0x01d09157a5610eb4.

This issue is happening only when we click on that link to create report. Crystal report is used here, but on other places also in the code. But the issue occurs only after clicking the link on a server.

Note: No looping in the code to generate report.
Can some one point out the reason for this issue? and how to rectify?

Answer (score 0):

This type of error log message indicates worker process crash, or application pool crash. There is no other information available in the logs apart from this message. Hence to get to the root cause of this crash, we need to collect memory dump at the time of crash, and analyze it to get the root cause.

[Here's the link with steps create memory dump and then analyze](https://web.archive.org/web/20190121152147/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chaun/2013/11/12/steps-to-catch-a-simple-crash-dump-of-a-crashing-process/).